# newly dynamically created (by javascript) html content cannot see the previously used javascript file in the head

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link (**A link**), which dynamically creates some html content into the page by a js file placed in the head content. This works well.

```
<head>
    <script src="my.js">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="A link">
    </div>
</body>
```

Than clicked the A link, and this is created:

```
<div>
     <a href="B link">
</div>
```

The newly created html content also contains a link (**B link**), which should use the same js file, as used before, but it seems, that the **B link** cannot see it, however the js file is still in the header content.

Works only if I put the js file in a script tag to the end of the dynamically created html content generated by **A link**, like this.

```
<div>
    <a href="B link">
    <script src="my.js">
</div>
```

But this means I load this js file twice. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Using jquery or pure js?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: @u_mulder I use jqery

Comment: Then use `on` or `live`-bindings.

Comment: .on, NOT live @u_mulder

Comment: With old versions `on` is not supported. As I don't know which version OP uses I recommended both.

Comment: Can you share how you are creating dynamic content on click of link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the newly created element to perform some action then you should use this technique using jquery.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.linkclass', function()
 {
       // Perform your action here.
       alert('I was clicked');
 });
```

**live** of Jquery is now obselete and is better to use **on**. In this way your all newly created element or already created elements having class as **.linkclass** will perform **alert();** action. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Does this mean, that I should always use .on instead of .click?

Comment: You are welcome. And no you can use on 'change', 'submit' etc instead of 'click' only as well. see this link http://api.jquery.com/on/ and plz accept this answer so it can help others in future from your question.

Comment: and this technique is better to use when you have many elements which are calling same function.